# Web component content not rendered

Tags: javascript, html

I am making my first web component but the shadow dom part is stopping the content from rendering. It's basically a box with a close button in the top right (not yet functional).

The problem is the hello world text momentarily appears and then disappears, presumably when the shadow dom is rendered. I am viewing it in Chrome (70).

Javascript file:

```
export class InfoBox extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.sRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        this.sRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
        .close{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            float: right;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="close">X</div>
        `;
    };
};
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Web component test bed</title>

        <!-- Load the polyfil for Edge. -->
        <script src="./scripts/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

        <script type=module>

            import { InfoBox } from './scripts/InfoBox.js';
            window.customElements.define('infobox-content', InfoBox);

        </script>

    </head>



    <body>

        <style>

            infobox-content{
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 100px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: #333333;
                color: #ffffff;
            }

        </style>

        <infobox-content>Hello World</infobox-content>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be to use the `<slot>` tag:

```
this.sRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
        .close{
            z-index: 20;
            position: relative;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            float: right;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        </style>
        <slot class="user">Your content here</slot>
        <div class="close">X</div>
        `;
```

Unless anyone has a better solution.
I still have to work out how to apply default styling to the user provided content, amongst many other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are suppose to set innerHTML of shadowRoot so create an element then use appendChild to add it. This should work;

```
export class InfoBox extends HTMLElement {

constructor() {

    super();

    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

};

connectedCallback() {
    console.log("heyo")
    let exampleDiv = document.createElement("div");
    exampleDiv.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    .close{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        float: right;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="close">X</div>
    `;

    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(exampleDiv);
}
```

};

window.customElements.define('infobox-content', InfoBox);